# Nutrition value: cold or warm milk?

Tags: milk, nutrient-composition

What is better: drinking cold milk or warm milk?

My question is only from the nutrition point of view. I am interested to know which one has a better nutrition value regardless of their side effects and other considerations.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both have been pasteurized, the nutritional value is the same...You're certainly not going to be drinking milk at pasteurization temperatures.

For raw milk, you have to weigh the risks of bacterial contamination. It's rare, but it can be exceedingly nasty.